# Running a Custom Action in WIX

Tags: c#, wix

I've created a managed custom action for a WIX project.  The custom action retrieves information about the machine from a file that is required during the user interface phase of the installation.  All of the examples that I've found assume that the custom action should be at the end of the installation and so have the pattern:

```
    <Binary Id="CustomActions.CA.dll" SourceFile="CustomActions.CA.dll" />
    <CustomAction Id="GetMachineInformation" Return="check" Execute="immediate" BinaryKey="CustomActions.CA.dll" DllEntry="GetMachineInformation" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="GetMachineInformation" After="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

which, as I understand it, should execute the custom action after everything is done.  How do I execute this custom action at the very beginning of the process before the first user interface window appears?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the sequence to be before the first event in the standard install execute sequence. This question seemed to already cover it

[Executing Custom Actions immediately in WIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639176/executing-custom-actions-immediately-in-wix)